# Plot of Kernel Cumulative Distribution Function in R

Tags: r, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution

I am trying to plot $\hat F(x)$ of Log-normal kernel in `R`.  Its a simple $\hat F(x)$ of lognormal distribution with some transformation proposed by Jin and Kawczak (2003).([Check  here if needed](http://down.aefweb.net/AefArticles/aef040106.pdf)).After transformation cdf becomes
$$\hat F(x)=\phi(\frac{lny-lnx}{\sqrt(4ln(1+h))})$$
where $h$ is bandwidth. 
**Q:** why my $\hat F(x)$ is moving downward?
Kindly provide the solution/suggestion in this matter. Thankx.
My `R` code is as:

```
k <- 200
    y<-c(306, 455, 210, 883, 310, 361, 218, 166, 170, 654, 728, 71, 567, 144, 613, 707, 61, 88,301, 81, 624, 371, 394, 520, 574, 118, 390, 12, 473, 26, 533, 107, 53, 122, 814, 93,731, 460, 153, 433, 145, 583, 95, 303, 519, 643, 765, 735, 189, 53, 246, 689, 65, 5,132, 687, 345, 444, 223, 175, 60, 163, 65, 208, 428, 230, 305, 11, 132, 226, 426, 705,363, 11, 176, 791, 95, 167, 284, 641, 147, 163, 655, 239, 88, 245, 30, 179, 310, 477,166, 450, 364, 107, 177, 156, 11, 429, 351, 15, 181, 283, 201, 524, 13, 212, 524, 288, 363, 442, 199, 550, 54, 558, 207, 92, 60, 293, 202, 353, 267, 371, 387, 457, 337, 201,222, 62, 353, 163, 31, 340, 229, 182, 156, 329, 291, 179, 268, 142, 194, 320, 181, 285,348, 197, 180, 186, 145, 350, 285, 110, 286, 270, 81, 131, 269, 135, 79, 59, 105, 239,13, 183, 116)
    ############################################
    n <- length(y)

     h<-0.79 * IQR(y) * length(y) ^ (-1/5)
     x <- seq(min(y) + 0.05, max(y), length = k)

     Fhat <- rep(0, k)
     for(j in 1:k) {
    for(i in 1:n) {
     PhiLN<- matrix(rep(0, k * n), ncol = k)
    PhiLN[i, j] <- pnorm((log(y[i])-log(x[j]))/(sqrt(4*log(1+h))))
    }
    Fhat[j] <- 1/n * (sum(PhiLN[, j]))
    }
    plot(x, Fhat, type = "l")
```

Comment: Maybe RoT = PI.  Or maybe they just happen to give the same result. I don't see any paradox here.

Comment: The $f$ argument is supposed to be a fraction of the data, not a bandwidth.  Probably both PI and RoT are greater than 1, so you get the result with $f=1$ in either case.

Answer (score 2):

The f argument is supposed to be a fraction of the data (between zero and one), not a bandwidth. PI and RoT are both ~ 12.9, therefore greater than 1.  The lowess function caps f at 1, so you get the result with f=1 in either case, as is easy to confirm.

Comment: its mean this is because of data type?